# Why I want to add an address to the stack pointer?

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly, msp430

I'm trying to understand the first [microcorruption](https://microcorruption.com/) challenge.

I want to ask about the first line of the main function.

Why would they add that address to the stack pointer?

[image: microcorruption]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the micro corruption challenge. Can you elaborate?

Comment: oh uhm... it's this website i meant https://microcorruption.com/.

Comment: What ISA is this?  MSP430 possibly?  http://www.ece.uah.edu/~milenka/cpe323-10S/lectures/cpe323msp430_ISA.pdf  It's a 16-bit ISA with those register names.  `0xff9c` is `-100` in 16-bit 2's complement, so probably this is reserving 100 bytes of stack space for main to use.

Comment: @PeterCordes but why it's negative?

Comment: @haruhi The stack grows down instead of up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a 16-bit ISA<sup>1</sup>, otherwise the disassembly makes no sense.

`0xff9c` is -100 in 16-bit 2's complement, so it looks like this is reserving 100 bytes of stack space for `main` to use.  (Stacks grow downward on most machines).  **It's not an address, just a small offset.**

See [MSP430 Assembly Stack Pointer Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374287/msp430-assembly-stack-pointer-behavior) for a detailed example of MSP430 stack layout and usage.

---

Footnote 1: MSP430 possibly? http://mspgcc.sourceforge.net/manual/x82.html it's a 16-bit ISA with those register names, and [those mnemonics](http://mspgcc.sourceforge.net/manual/x223.html), and I think its machine code uses variable-length 2 or 4 byte instructions.

It's definitely not ARM; `call` and `jmp` are not ARM mnemonics; that would be `bl` and `b`.  Also, ARM uses `op dst, src1, src2` syntax, while this disassembly uses `op src, dst`.

Comment: Thank you. The manual of this challenge also said that it was MSP430. Sorry I should have mentioned it... But I want to ask why it's -100 and not 100?

Comment: @haruhi: because it's being used with an `add` instruction, not `sub`.  To move SP downward, you have to add a negative number.  Or do you mean why does `0xff9c` represent -100 instead of +100?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement.  If you mean why does the stack grow down: [Why does the stack grow downward?](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/137640).  And yes you definitely should have mentioned what ISA you were asking about.